# Как обновить страницу только после удаления файла?

Tags: php

Как обновить страницу сразу после удаления файла, и после выводить сообщение об успешном удалении(список файлов при этом уже обновлен), подскажите пожалуйста. 
(используя только PHP)
Возможно как то выводить список файлов еще раз после удаления?

```
<?php
        $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 0;
        $skip = PER_PAGE * $page;
        $entries = array();

        if ($handle = opendir(ROOT_DIR . ARTICLE_DIR)) {
            $count = 0;
            while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($entry !='.' and $entry != '..') {
                    $count++;
                    if ($count < $skip || $count > $skip + PER_PAGE) {
                    continue;
                    }
                    $entries[] = ROOT_DIR . ARTICLE_DIR . $entry;
                    array_multisort(array_map('filectime', $entries), SORT_DESC, $entries);
                }
            }
        }closedir($handle);

        $pages = (int)$count;
        if ($count % PER_PAGE)
        $pages ++;

        foreach($entries as $entry) {

            $file_name = explode('/', $entry);
            $file_name = strstr(end($file_name), '.', true);

            if (!empty($_GET['destroy'])){
                if (file_exists($_GET['destroy'])){

                    unlink($_GET['destroy']); // УДАЛЕНИЕ !!

                    echo '<div class="success">Файл "'.$file_name.'" удален.</div>';

                }   
            }
            ?>
                <ul>

                <?php

                echo '<li><a href="index.php?show='.urlencode($entry).'">'.$file_name.'</a><a class="destroy" href="index.php?destroy='.urlencode($entry).'">'.'Удалить</a></li>';

                ?>

                </ul>

            <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
if (!empty($_GET['destroy'])){
  if (file_exists($_GET['destroy']))
  {
    unlink($_GET['destroy']); // УДАЛЕНИЕ !!
    echo '<div class="success">Файл "'.$file_name.'" удален.</div>';
    //вся соль в следующей строке 
    echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(1);}, 5000);</script>';
  }
}
```

Upd:

```
  if ((!empty($_GET['destroy']) and (file_exists($_GET['destroy']))
  {
    unlink($_GET['destroy']); // УДАЛЕНИЕ !!
    echo '<div class="success">Файл "'.$file_name.'" удален.</div>';
    echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(1);}, 5000);</script>';      
  } else
  foreach($entries as $entry) 
  {
    $file_name = explode('/', $entry);
    $file_name = strstr(end($file_name), '.', true);
    echo "<ul>";
    echo '<li><a href="index.php?show='.urlencode($entry).'">'.$file_name.'</a><a class="destroy" href="index.php?destroy='.urlencode($entry).'">'.'Удалить</a></li>';
    echo "</ul>";      
  }
```

Comment: Да, пробовала) но в таком случае если нажать на удаление следующего файла до перезагрузки, то удалиться следующий за ним

Comment: @Nastya Тогда вам надо уточнить условия вопроса, и делать либо "всплывающее окно" с асинхронным запросом(без обновления страницы) либо блокировать возможность "удалять" другие файлы. так же например можно изменить значение таймера на меньшее и не выводить ссылки если файл только что был удален(и страница еще не обновлена).

Comment: дополнила условия

Comment: @Nastya Обновил ответ.